# Is there any way to kill a OSX notification in swift4 upon process exit

Tags: swift, macos

I been searching around for hours trying to find answers but i cant find any useful info on this.

Basically i have a super basic command line app  that just creates a notification. It works but when the CLI process is terminated, the OSX notification still exists. When clicked, it does nothing.

This app is a Swift 4 coca app, it uses the *AppDelegate* class and extends `NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate`

In **applicationWillTerminate()**, i would think this function would be called upon the process existing.

I was wondering is it possible run to run a command when the process is terminated via SIGTERM/SIGINT and/or close the notification when the process exit?

Any help is appreciated! Im sort of new to Swift, its been giving me a good swift kick in the rump :)

Answer (score 1):

`applicationWillTerminate` is called in response to calling `NSApplication.terminate(_:)`. Cocoa calls this in response to user interface actions like using File -> Quit, but it does not register signal handlers. One simple way to register such signal handlers for your command-line application could be to use `DispatchSource.makeSignalSource`:

```
signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN)
let sigint = DispatchSource.makeSignalSource(signal: SIGINT, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
sigint.setEventHandler {
    NSApp.terminate(nil)
}
sigint.resume()
```

You can do the same thing for any other signal that can be handled, like `SIGQUIT` or `SIGTERM` (although I think that it's probably fair to leave `SIGTERM` alone).

I suggest that you keep `sigint` as an instance variable to ensure that the object doesn't go away. I'm not sure that it is necessary, though.

The functions that you call in a signal dispatch source event handler do not have to be async-signal-safe because their handling is deferred. See [Dispatch Sources: Monitoring Signals](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH103-SW4) for the details (the document uses the C API, but the semantics are the same).